# Given an Object, How can I programatically tell what Interfaces it supports?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection, interface

Given this:

```
Interface IBase {string X {get;set;}}
Interface ISuper {string Y {get;set;}}

class Base : IBase {etc...}
class Super : Base, ISuper {etc...}

void Questionable (Base b) {
  Console.WriteLine ("The class supports the following interfaces... ")
  // The Magic Happens Here
}
```

What can I replace "The Magic" with to display the supported interfaces on object b?

Yes, I know by being of class Base it supports "IBase", the real hierarchy is more complex that this. :)

Thanks!
-DF5

EDIT: Now that I've seen the answer I feel stupid for not tripping over that via Intellisense. :)

Thanks All! -DF5

Comment: When you have the interface list, what are you going to do with it?

Comment: Feed it to a method that knows how to generate UI components (based on the Interfaces) to allow the user to manipulate property values (via the Interface) of some objects.

IE: If the object supports the IDateTimeFormat, then I should present a drop down of common date time formats.

Comment: Some objects have 3~5 UI editable properties...

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The Magic :

```
foreach (Type iface in b.GetType().GetInterfaces())
    Console.WriteLine(iface.Name);
```

Answer (score 8):

b.GetType().[GetInterfaces](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.type.getinterfaces.aspx)()

Answer (score 2):

```
foreach (var t in b.GetType().GetInterfaces())
{
    Console.WriteLine(t.ToString());
}
```

Comment: Is there any good reason to prefer var over Type? I tend to avoid var as much as possible but without good justification...

Comment: Diadistis, search for "to var or not to var".

Comment: I always use var in foreach loops unless I'm iterating over a collection that doesn't implement IEnumerable<T>. The call to "GetInterfaces" makes it clear what type "t" is in this example, so why bother repeating it in the declaration? (IMHO)

Answer (score 2):

Heh,  I saw the Console.WriteLine and thought you were looking for a string representation.  Here it is anyways

```
public string GetInterfacesAsString(Type type) { 
  return type.GetInterfaces().Select(t => t.ToString()).Aggregate(x,y => x + "," + y);
}
```

Comment: GetInterfaces returns all interfaces, not only immediate.

Comment: That's not entirely correct either :) You have to deal with nested interfaces, which should be converted from CLR to C# notation.

Comment: @Ilya, picky picky :).  What about interfaces which are entirely unrepresentable in C#?  For intance <>Foo is a legal interface name.

Comment: @JaredPar, Well, not just picky :) I wanted to put some attention to the topic of what is the purpose of constructing comma-delimited list of interfaces, how this list is going to be used and what sense does it make.

Comment: @Ilya, definately agree on the need to understand intent.  There are lots of issues that come once you start trying to convert metadata/reflection back into a real langauge.  See deccompiled F# for example

Comment: @JaredPar, yeah, I know, We make ReSharper ;)